# Discord.py won't allow code blocks through ```

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot and am trying to get the bot to print text inside discord markdown code blocks, which involves three backticks before and after the targeted text. However, when I include the backticks in the output statement the bot won't start, with this error appearing in the shell:
`ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:719)`.

So far I've found that using a single backtick, `` ("`Text Here`") ``, does work and produces the correct result for a single one (slightly different code block style). Variants such as putting it in a multi line text block in python doesn't work either.

The code before trying to turn the text to a code block:

```
@bot.command()
async def ping():
    await bot.say("Pong!")
```

And what I tried, along with other variants, that didn't work and stopped the bot from running:

````
@bot.command()
async def ping():
    await bot.say("```Pong!```")

@bot.command()
async def ping():
    await bot.say("""
```Pong!```
""")
````

Is there any major reason behind this making it not work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a raw string? Like [this](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug from [discord.py], but with Discord itself. All code blocks must have line breaks at the beginning and end. The code you should use is:

````
@bot.command()
async def ping():
    await bot.say("```\nPong!\n```")
````

This is because Discord, like Stack Overflow uses code block highlighting. It thinks that the specified language is "Pong!".